# Attempting to resize canvas element, but crop effect is occurring

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a toy project in Javascript.  The goal is to have two different canvas elements with different sizes.  I want to show a smaller image in the browser, on which the user can apply effects to, and when the time comes to save, the changes will be applied to the larger image.

Basically, my workflow is

1. User drags and drops an image into the drop zone
2. ImageWrapper object is created within the `FileReader.onload` callback
3. Two canvas elements are created: `originalCanvas` and `previewCanvas`
4. `previewCanvas` is resized with aspect ratio to fit the preview container

My issue is that the downscale operation results in a crop, rather than a resize.

My code is

```
//executes on the drop event
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e){

  canvasImage = new ImageWrapper();
  canvasImage.init(e.target.result, "preview", "center_align");
  canvasImage.scaleAspect("image_preview");
  document.getElementById("drop_image_container")
      .appendChild(canvasImage.previewCanvas.canvas);
```

I created an `ImageWrapper` object to contain several fields:

```
var ImageWrapper = function(){

  //set up the original and preview canvases
  var originalCanvas = new CanvasImage(),
    previewCanvas = new CanvasImage();

  //inner object to allow for original and preview canvas objects.
  function CanvasImage(){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        image = new Image();

    return {
        canvas : canvas,
        context : context,
        image : image
    };
  }

  function init(src, id, classes){
    previewCanvas.canvas.id = id;
    previewCanvas.canvas.className = classes;

    originalCanvas.image.src = src;
    previewCanvas.image.src = src;

    originalCanvas.canvas.height = originalCanvas.image.naturalHeight;
    originalCanvas.canvas.width = originalCanvas.image.naturalWidth;
    previewCanvas.canvas.height = previewCanvas.image.naturalHeight;
    previewCanvas.canvas.width = previewCanvas.image.naturalWidth;

    previewCanvas.image.onload = function(){

        previewCanvas.context.drawImage(previewCanvas.image, 0, 0);
        originalCanvas.context.drawImage(originalCanvas.image, 0, 0);
    }
  }
```

The `init()` function is intended to create the two canvas elements with the default image size.  Then `scaleAspect()` is called with the id of the preview container, which allows me to calculate the new dimensions of the canvas while maintaining the aspect ratio.

```
/*  Scales the canvas element while maintaining aspect ratio of the original
*/
function scaleAspect(previewContainer){

  var container = processParam(previewContainer),
      width = previewCanvas.canvas.width,
      height = previewCanvas.canvas.height;

  var ratio = [container.width()/width, container.height()/height];
  ratio = Math.min(ratio[0], ratio[1]);

  previewCanvas.canvas.width = width * ratio;
  previewCanvas.canvas.height = height * ratio;

  previewCanvas.context.drawImage(previewCanvas.image, 0, 0, 
      previewCanvas.canvas.width, previewCanvas.canvas.height);

}
```

Once this function is complete, the `previewCanvas.canvas` element is added as a child of the drop container.

This drawImage is executing, but the results are not what I expected.  The preview container is 500x500 pixels, which makes the new image to be 375x500 pixels in size. This drawImage is executing a crop operation, although there is a flicker on the execution.  I can briefly see the resized image before the crop sets in.

Is it possible that the `originalCanvas` element is being drawn even though it is not bound to the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [drawImage(image, x, y)](http://www.javascripture.com/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage_HTMLImageElement_Number_Number) version you are using will draw the image at its native pixel size on the canvas.  Instead, you should use the [drawImage(image, x, y, width, height)](http://www.javascripture.com/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage_HTMLImageElement_Number_Number_Number_Number) version which lets you specify the destinations size when drawing the image into the canvas.

Comment: That was the solution and I found it before you posted your answer.  From my initial reading about the extra `drawImage` params, it appeared to me that the `width` and `height` parameters were specifying the source dimensions, not the destination.